# Trying to open Sql connection to Northwind database in C# with build error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am currently trying to learn how to connect an Sql server database to C#. I am trying to connect to the Northwind sample DB but I keep getting a build error. Can someone help point me in the direction where I am going wrong, here is my code and thank you in advance:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestConnection1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string conString = "Data Source=TONYSPC\anthony;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();

            if (con.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string q = "insert into Employees(EmployeeID,FirstName)values('"+txtId.Text.ToString()+"','"+txtName.Text.ToString()+"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection made Successfully..!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you indicate what is your build error?

Comment: ALWAYS provide the error message and specify where in the code it occurs. We shouldn't have to trawl through the entire (improperly formatted) code hoping to see an issue when you can tell us exactly where and what it is.

Comment: Look at `Employees` schema. `EmployeeID` is identity column and you cannot insert a value in it explicitly. `FirstName` and `LastName` are `not null` columns so their values **must** be provided. Side note: Never concatenate user-provided values in a SQL query. Always use parameters.